# Convert a view to a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a view `view_a` in my database on which several other views depend (`view_b`, `view_c`, etc.)

I need to convert `view_a` into a table, because I no longer want the information in this relation to be dynamic and I need the capability to edit rows manually.

Can I replace `view_a` with a table without doing a `DROP CASCADE` and redefining all views that reference `view_a`?

Clarification: I want `view_b` and `view_c` to continue to reference `view_a` (now a table).  I want to replace a view with a table, not have a table in addition to a view.

Comment: `create table table_name as select * from view_a`

Comment: @Lucas this creates a table _in addition_ to the view.  I want to _replace_ the view atomically.

Comment: just update the view_b and view_c to the new table you created

Comment: as in the question, I want to do this _without redefining all views that reference `view_a`_.

Comment: Then no, it is not possible to do this. You cannot redefine a views query without dropping and recreating it. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-alterview.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was able to resolve this without tracking down and redefining all objects that depend on `view_a`, at the expense of adding one level of useless redirection.

```
-- create a copy of the result of view_a
CREATE TABLE table_a AS SELECT * FROM view_a;

-- redefine view_a to its own result
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_a AS SELECT * FROM table_a;
```

Comment: Hi, I'm new to databases and data management. I'm looking at something similar. The solution: nice answer to whomever says 'Not possible'. I have got a question for what concerns this way of working though. If you redefine view_a as a copy of table_a, then won't you still have an extra cost when you get through the view to the table? That was not the gist of the question, I understand that. But having the table enables you to get rid of that cost. Is a view that mirrors a table such a low effort for a DB?  Again - only just digging into data.